# How to paint custom combox box button?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a custom combox (sample code given below) in c#. How to paint the combo button and down glyph only with different colors so that it can be matched with theme applied to other third party controls?

```
public class CustomCombo : Control
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    private Rectangle GetDownRectangle()
    {
        return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - 16, 0, 16, this.ClientSize.Height);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        ControlPaint.DrawComboButton(e.Graphics, GetDownRectangle(), ButtonState.Flat);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBoxRenderer.cs,28f45b7a03475ba8

Comment: added the line below in paint method but did not help. I'v got a white box with red crossed diagonally.
ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, GetDownRectangle(), System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.ComboBoxState.Normal);